# filesize(): stat failed for file.zip

Tags: php, zip

I am creating a zip file combining 2 files but showing error while opening it.But when i open it with a code editor it shows some error.

### My main code is:

```
<?php
    $files = array(
                'localhost/apache_pb2_ani.gif',
                'localhost/apache_pb2.png');
                $zipname = 'file.zip';
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                  $zip->addFile($file);
                }
                $zip->close();
            //if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
            header('Content-Type: application/zip');
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
            readfile($zipname);
    ?>
```

And the errors are :

`Warning:filesize(): stat failed for file.zip in C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php on line 19`

`Warning:  readfile(file.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\download.php on line 20`

What seems to be error?

Comment: Remove localhost/ from the array. Only file name with extension is required for eg: apache_pb2_ani.gif , also make sure that you are keeping files at the same place where this code is located.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the warnings if the paths to the files I use in the `$files` array are not correct.

Are you sure that the paths (with the 'localhost/') to your images are correct?

```
$files = array(
    'localhost/apache_pb2_ani.gif',
    'localhost/apache_pb2.png'
);
```

Comment: Yes when i enter them to address bar they show me the correct images

Comment: What happens then you test you code without the 'localhost/'?
In which directory are the images?